# How can I implement passport with the bcrypt code I already have?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, passport.js, bcrypt

You will not believe me, I tried more than tons of things when trying to implement passport with the bcrypt code I already have, for almost 15 hours today, reading docs and trying different things, basically I tortured myself.

Please anyone have a look into my project and couple of the codes I will post em here, but please help me, I would love to combine passport with the bcrypt code I have, I know some code will get deleted and some added which is normal lawl, but please anyone HEEEELP
the codes will you an insight into what things look like but please take your time and look into my project on my GitHub THAAANKS <3

https://github.com/tigerabrodi/blogcms

auth controller

```
const path = require('path');
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const User = require("../models/user");


function getErrorMessage(req) {
    let message = req.flash("error");
    if (message.length > 0) {
        message = message[0];
    } else {
        message = null;
    }
    return message;
}


exports.getLoginPage = (req, res) => {
    res.render("blog/login", {
        pageTitle: "login",
        path: "/login",
        errorMessage: getErrorMessage(req)
    });
}


exports.getsignUpPage = (req, res) => {
    res.render("blog/signup", {
        pageTitle: "signup",
        path: "/signup",
        errorMessage: getErrorMessage(req)
    });
}


exports.postLogin = async (req, res, next) => {
    const {
        username,
        password
    } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({
            username
        })
        if (!user) {
            req.flash("error", "Invalid Email or Password.");
            res.redirect("/login");
        }
        const correctCredentials = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

        if (!correctCredentials) {
            req.flash("error", "Invalid Email or Password.");
            res.redirect("/login");
        }


        req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
        req.session.user = user;
        const result = await req.session.save(err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.redirect("/");
        });


    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return req.flash("error", "Invalid Email or Password.");
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
}


exports.postLogout = (req, res, next) => {
    req.session.destroy(err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.redirect("/");
    })
}


exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {

    const {
        username,
        password
    } = req.body;

    const user = new User({
        username,
        password
    });

    User.findOne({
        username
    }, (err, userExists) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (userExists) {
            req.flash("error", "Email exists already, please pick a different one.");

            return res.redirect("/signup");
        }

        user.save(error => {
            if (error) return next(error);
            res.redirect("/login");
        });
    });
};
```

user model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");


const userSchema = new Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},

password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
});


userSchema.pre("save", async function save(next) {
const user = this;
if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
user.password = hashedPassword;
next();
});



module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

app.js

```
require('dotenv').config({path: "node.env"});
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const flash = require("connect-flash");

const session = require("express-session");
const MongoDBStore = require("connect-mongodb-session")(session);
const errorController = require('./controllers/error');

const mongodb_uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const app = express();
const csrf = require("csurf");
const User = require("./models/user");

const store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: mongodb_uri,
    collection: "sessions"
});


const csrfProtection = csrf();


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');


const adminRoutes = require("./routes/admin");
const blogRoutes = require("./routes/blog");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(
    session({
        secret: process.env.SECRET,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
        },
        store: store,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,

    })
);


app.use(flash());
app.use(csrfProtection);


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        return next();
    }
    User.findById(req.session.user._id)
    .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            return next();
        }
        req.user = user;
        next();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
    res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
    next();
});


app.use(adminRoutes);
app.use(blogRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);


app.use(errorController.get404);


mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);


mongoose.connect(mongodb_uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});


app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("listening to port 3000")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hash the password ***before*** inserting the user in the database.
You can do something like this, in your `postSignup` function:

```
 exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {

    const {
        username,
        password
    } = req.body;

    User.findOne({
        username
    }, (err, userExists) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (userExists) {
            req.flash("error", "Email exists already, please pick a different one.");

            return res.redirect("/signup");
        }

        bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hashed) =>{
           const user = {
              username,
              hashed 
          };

          User.insert(user);
        });
    });
};
```

And then when the user logs in, you need to compare the hashed password with the one that the user typed. But I see you are already doing that with `const correctCredentials = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)`.